# How to preserve whitespace in ANTLR4 when reading an string?

Tags: antlr4

I am creating a grammar which will be used to create a lexical analyser and parser for C#. This will take the below input and will output SQL.

`(path.path.path="how to do something")`

at the moment I am ignoring whitespace by using:

`WS              :   [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;               // Skips whitespace`

The problem is, when I'm reading the content within the quotes, I need to preserve the whitespace as it will be used in a search.
How do I go about doing this?
Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

Here is my current attempt at parsing strings:

```
TEXT            :   [a-zA-Z_]+;
```

There isn't much as I have just run into this problem, but I can't find a solution that I understand how to implement.

I have also added

```
@lexer::members{
    //Lexer members

    //Used to preserve whitespace when reading in statements
    boolean ignore=true;
}
```

I have seen something similar to this dotted about.
Where the value of `ignore` will determine whether the whitespace will skip. I have also changed my whitespace rule to:

```
WS              :   [ \t\r\n]+ {if(ignore) skip();};
```

But I'm unsure how I would set `ignore` to `false` before scanning over the statement and how I would change it back to `true` after I have finished.

**Edit 2**

I have copied over the entirety of my grammar file:

```
// Grammar for Search Criteria
grammar SearchGen;

@members{
    //Lexer members

    //Used to preserve whitespace when reading in statements
    boolean ignore=true;
}

r               :   block_clause*
                |   block
                |   statement;

// block = ( statement CLAUSE statement )
block           :   OPEN_BRACKET start_segment+ end_segment CLOSE_BRACKET;

block_clause    :   block clause;

start_segment   :   statement clause;

end_segment     :   statement;

statement       :   OPEN_BRACKET path search_term CLOSE_BRACKET; //Change TEXT to allows for blah.blah="hiv"

path            :   TEXT '.' TEXT '.' TEXT;

clause          :   NOT | OR | AND | WITHIN;

search_term     :   OPERATOR SEARCH_TYPE;

OPEN_BRACKET    :   '(';

CLOSE_BRACKET   :   ')';

UNDERSCORE      :   '_';

SEARCH_TYPE     :   '"' (~["\\] | '\\' .)* '"';

OPERATOR        :   EQUALS | GREATER_THAN | LESS_THAN | AMP; //Maybe put the amp and quotes in TEXT/

GREATER_THAN    :   '>' | '&gt;';

LESS_THAN       :   '<' | '&lt;';

QUOTE           :   '"' | '&amp;quot;';

EQUALS          :   '=';

AMP             :   '&' | '&amp;';

NOT             :   'NOT' | 'not';

OR              :   'OR' | 'or';

AND             :   'AND' | 'and';

WITHIN          :   'WITHIN' | 'within';



//Possible problem : If a keyword that the user is looking for matches one of the above tokens

TEXT            :   [a-zA-Z_]+; // Include Underscore

DIGIT           :   [0-9]+;

// yyyy-mm-dd

DATE            : YEAR'-'MONTH'-'DAY;

YEAR            :   [1-2][(0-9)][(0-9)][(0-9)];

MONTH           :   [0][1-9] | [1-9] | [1][(0-2)];

DAY             :   [0][1-9] | [1-2][0-9] | [3][0-1];

WS              :   [ \t\r\n]+ ->skip;               // Skips whitespace
```

Comment: So your current attempt at parsing string discards whitespace? If so, please show that attempt.

Comment: @sepp2k I have added more.

Comment: I don't mean to sound contrary, but how is `TEXT: [a-zA-Z_]+;` an attempt at parsing strings? Strings usually have quotes and can contain characters other than letters. That looks much more like an attempt to parse identifiers.

Comment: Does your rule for parsing strings look like this: `string: '"' TEXT* '"';`?

Comment: @sepp2k Sorry I am very new to this. What I posted was my Identifier I believe? I have copied over my entire grammar file.I don't believe I have a rule for parsing the string, I know that after a ```path``` will come an operator, and ```TEXT``` surrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like you handle strings in your first alternative of `SEARCH_TYPE`, namely:

```
SEARCH_TYPE     :   '"'TEXT'"'
```

Now the problem with that rule isn't that it ignores spaces - it's that spaces aren't allowed at all because `TEXT` does not match spaces. So if you entered something like `" hello "`, you wouldn't get a string without the spaces, you'd get a syntax error because that input does not match the `'"'TEXT'"'` pattern. Only "hello" would be a valid string according to that rule. Characters other than letters or underscores are also not allowed, which is different than how strings usually work.

Presumably you want to allow anything inside double-quotes strings except for double quotes (and in most programming languages there's also some way to escape double quotes). So we can just use an inverted character class that matches anything except double quotes:

```
SEARCH_TYPE: '"' ~'"'* '"';
```

Now to allow escaping, we might also allow a backslash followed by any character (including a double quote):

```
SEARCH_TYPE: '"' (~["\\] | '\\' .)* '"';
```

Note that this also allows empty strings, which your original rule did not.

So now our strings can actually contain spaces without producing a syntax error. So how do we prevent spaces being ignored? We don't because we don't need to. `WS              :   [ \t\r\n]+ ->skip;` simply means that if the lexer were to produce a `WS` token, it just skips to the next token instead. This will not affect what happens inside other lexer rules. In other words: The `WS` rules skips whitespace *between* tokens, not *inside* tokens. So whitespace being ignored is simply not a problem at all.

PS: You grammar also contains a `QUOTE` token that you never use, which looks like a mistake. Further the `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY` rules should probably be declared as fragments as they can never be matched on their own anyway.

Comment: I have changed my ```SEARCH_TYPE``` to match yours but when testing it still fails. I have tested it against an argument with and without spaces.

Comment: @DanielJones I've made a mistake in my syntax for inverted character classes. It's fixed now.

Comment: Unfortunately I still can't get it to work. I have tested against both arguments again and the one with spaces fails.

Comment: @DanielJones Which input did you try and what was the error message? And did you make any changes to the grammar other than changing the rule for strings (if so, please post your current version of the grammar)?

Comment: I have just updated my code to what it is now.
The test case is: 

```((Events.Event.Comments="sodium valproate") OR (Events.Event.Comments="meals on wheels"))```

Both test case's use this template, just one doesn't use the spaces.
The error I'm receiving is:

```line 1:24 no viable alternative at input '((Events.Event.Comments="' ```

Comment: @DanielJones If I copy the grammar from your most recent edit into a .g4 file and then run it on the input from your comment, it works fine without any errors. Are you sure the grammar you posted is exactly the same as the one you're using?

Comment: I am certain, I just copied my pasted code and tested it and it came back with an error. That is weird.

Comment: @DanielJones Are there maybe any lexer rules after `WS` in your real code that you missed when copy and pasting? Or maybe you forgot to re-run ANTLR after changing the grammar or you forgot to re-compile the Java code after re-running ANTLR. I also find it odd that the error message says "line 1:24" when the input it complains about is at the beginning of the string (so I'd expect "line 1:0").

Comment: I use CTRL+A to highlight all of my code and paste it. I have re-run ANTLR and re-compiled using java. Although the test case passes when there are no spaces and fails when there are, is it possible that something at the beginning of the string is causing it to fail?

Comment: @DanielJones Are you invoking the parser using `grun` or from Java code? Can you post the exact `grun` command you're running or your Java code?

Comment: I am invoking it from cmd using ```grun SearchGen r -gui```. I have also compiled the parser to use in a C# Project and I'm getting the same error there.

Comment: @DanielJones And the input you enter is `((Events.Event.Comments="sodium valproate") OR (Events.Event.Comments="meals on wheels"))` and nothing else just like in your comment and then you press Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z and then you get the error message you said? What output do you get if you add the `-tokens` command line option to `grun`?

Comment: That is the input that I have been using. I have run it again with to ```-tokens``` option and have caopied my output to a gitst:
https://gist.github.com/Dannyj98/e4d84785c54f257a41563a70b6eb270a

Comment: Apologies, your regex works perfectly. For some reason the Code Editor (VS Code) I was coding in wasn't saving my SearchGen.g4 changes and so I would be compiling an old copy. Not sure why this was happening.Thank you.